# Amazon S3 bucket file download get corrupted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-7

I am trying to download file from s3 bucket but when file is downloaded it not open its corrupted.

I have checked all solution here but its not solved my issue.

here is my function.

```
public function get(string $path): string
{
    if ($this->storage->exists($path)) {
        return $this->storage->get($path);
    } else {
        try {
            $realPath = substr($path, strpos($path, '.com/') + 5);
            return $this->storage->disk('s3')->get($realPath);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(
                'File not Found',
                Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you download manually using S3 console, is the file correct?

Comment: @Marcin I did not check it, let me check

Comment: @Marcin it is downloading from console.

Comment: So at least now you know, that the file is fine. The issue must be with your php code.